# Visual studio 2022 WinForm publish folder

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, visual-studio-2022

i have created a WinForm application and i tried to publish it but i have many questions about this publish process.

1. Why does Visual studio create the app folder in C:\Users\'Username'\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0 ?
2. Is there a way install the app .exe in another folder such as "ProgramFiles"?
3. How does this publish thing really work, is there a documentation about it?
4. What is the AppName.application file that is created after publishing?

I am worried about this because i want to create a Themes folder and i don't want the app folder to be so deep into the folder tree.

Comment: You need something like installshield or Innosetup (free)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app folder in C:\Users'Username'\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0 is a system folder, it is used to hold temporary data for .Net Framework apps installed on your PC.
you have nothing to worry about with that folder . . .

You can install the .exe and publish the solution in the folders that you want,
you can do it by using ClickOnce deployment to a folder.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-publish-a-clickonce-application-using-the-publish-wizard?view=vs-2022) is a Microsoft documentation how to use it.